# cmd gives me an error i was unexpected this time in a batch rename loop

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-rename

I am very new to cmd and I have a problem rename a batch of .jpg files. I found this script and it gives me the error i was unexpected this time.

for i in *.jpg; do mv -i "$i" ${RANDOM}.jpg

I did cd ¨path¨and typed that scrit and it gave me that error. Any idea what am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a batch command, it is a Linux (or Unix) shell command.  Are you trying to come up with a random name for each of the JPG files? .. please give us the purpose and someone here can help you.

Comment: This is simple to pull off in batch (but not as simple as Linux shell script).. but we do need to understand the purpose.  Also, a random number does not guarantee a unique outcome which might make your logic break. :)  A better option would be to use a [GUID/UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).. this guarantees uniqueness.  Happy to help.. just let us know what you need.

Comment: If you're working with WIndows, you're better off learning to work with **PowerShell** rather than **Command Prompt**. Per this [answer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/77e51894-c591-469f-b3d3-982ab4f76ca7/if-else-if-condition-in-batch-files?forum=ITCG).

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea what am I missing?

As mentioned in the comments, this command is a Linux shell command. It isn't designed to be run in Windows `cmd`. Windows doesn't know how to parse it in order to do what you want.

A comparable batch file for Windows might be:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

dir /b "*.jpg" > files

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (files) do copy /-y "%%i" !random!.jpg

del files
```

You could save this as e.g. `random_files_names.bat`.

**Important Bits**

- [setlocal](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) [EnableDelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) allows certain variables (in this case, the special variable [%random%](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-random.html)) "to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time". If this wasn't enabled, the random variable generated by `%random%` would be generated once at the start of the script but wouldn't change to another value through each loop cycle. `!` are also used in place of `%` because of this (so `%random%` becomes `!random!`).
- `dir /b "*.jpg" > files` and `del files` create (and delete) a temporary list of e.g. all the `*.jpg` files in a directory. [dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) with the `/b` option includes just the file names, rather than including the full path to each file. Creating this temporary file bypassed a small issue for me where an already renamed file was copied when using `dir /b` directly in the `for` loop.
- `for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (files) do copy /-y "%%i" !random!.jpg` does two things:

  1. Reads lines (filenames) from a text file (`for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (files)` in a [for](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) loop.
  2. Copies the file to the same directory (via [copy](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html)) with a random name (`copy /-y "%%i" !random!.jpg`). In this case, `/-y` serves the same purpose as `-i` in the original example (i.e. manually confirm overwriting of files with the same name, see Linux [mv](https://ss64.com/bash/mv.html)).
- Note that you can substitute [ren](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html) (rename) or [move](https://ss64.com/nt/move.html) for `copy`, as needed (though only `move` has the `/-y` option in this case). But please see *Caveats* below.

**Caveats**

Be aware that `%random%` only generates integers from 0 to 32,767 (inclusive) and may produce duplicates. [The ss64 page on generating random numbers for cmd](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-random.html) goes into more detail.

This means there is a chance that the same "random" name may be generated for two (or more) different files. So `ren` or `move` could be dangerous here. `copy /-y` partially mitigates some of the problems duplicate names might produce by not overwriting any original files *automatically* (though it could still replace them). However, it would likely be better to find another source of file names (ideally unique names, as again stated in the comments). The page on random number generation linked above also has a JavaScript alternative to `%random%` that can be run in `cmd`, which may arguably be a better choice than `%random%` itself.

Comment: Nice answer (and very well formatted) but as I pointed out, there is no guarantee of a unique file name using the random variable.  You gave him the exact thing he asked for but what he asked for is not a good solution to anything.